# Can't connect my iPhone 5 to my iPhone 8 hotspot

Tags: iphone, wifi

I'm currently trying to connect an iPhone 5 (10.3.4) to the hotspot of an iPhone 8 (15.3), but it keeps giving a "Unable to join the network" error. The iPhone 5 connects fine to other wifi networks and other devices connect without a problem to the iPhone 8 hotspot.

I've reset the network settings on the iPhone 5 and restarted both devices. Anything else I could try to make this work?

Comment: @Thinkr thanks but these don't help

Comment: This may be a carrier restriction on the iPhone 8.  Are both phones on the same carrier?  Is the 8 unlocked?

Comment: Can it join other people's hotspots?